# If possible, what is the Solr query syntax to filter by doc size?

Tags: solr

Solr 4.3.0

I want to find the larger size documents.

I'm trying to build some test data for testing memory usage, but I keep getting the smaller sized documents. So, if I could add a doc size clause to my query it would help me find more suitable documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of this possibility, most likely there is no support for it.

I could see one possible approach - you could add size of the document during indexing in some separate field, which will later use to filter on.

Another possible case - is to use [TermVectorComponent](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-term-vector-component.html), which could return term vectors for matched documents, which could lead to some understanding of "how big" this document is. Not easy and simple, though.
Example of the possibly useful [output](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermVectorComponentExampleOptions):

Third possible option (kudos to [MatsLindh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/137650/matslindh) for the idea): to use [sorting function](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#Sort_By_Function) `norm()` for a specific field. There are some limitations:

- You need to use some classic similarity
- The field you're sorting on should contains norms

Example of the sorting function: `sort:norm(field_name) desc`

Comment: An idea: how would sorting by `norm()` for the field end up?

Comment: @MatsLindh, I give it a try, first of all, it requires a TFIDFSimilarity (which i found strange) and second, it requires norms to be enabled, which isn't always the case, but definetely could be an option, of course.

Comment: Not clear on what "norm" is. Using the offsets for terms I'm expecting near the end of a document should give me an idea of the size. Thanks

Comment: bah, no tvrh handler running on the solr I'm using.